# Is there a way, in VS Code, to warn me before pushing git changes to a distant branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I often do the same mistake, I do some corrections (or modifications) on my code, forgot to create a new branch for it and push it directly on the *develop* branch of my Gitlab repo.

Is there a way, in VS Code, to be warmed before pushing changes to a selected branch of the distant repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since May 2022 (version 1.68), it is now possible to use `git.branchProtection` and `git.branchProtectionPrompt` to protect, directly from VS Code, some Git branches.

That's exactly what I was looking for.

[See this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150723) (at the time of writing, I can't find any documentation).

Answer (score 2):

You could also protect the branch by making it protected and only allow pull requests in GitLab:

> ## Require everyone to submit merge requests for a protected branch
>
> You can force everyone to submit a merge request, rather than allowing
> them to check in directly to a protected branch. This setting is
> compatible with workflows like the GitLab workflow.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#require-everyone-to-submit-merge-requests-for-a-protected-branch

The push will be rejected, just like the pre-push hook.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook.

Inside the hook script examine the branch used and ask the user if he wants to push and if not return a 1 otherwise return a 0.

You can use any language you want to write the script.

Look at the `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample`

Comment: That's a good idea but how do I interact with VS Code ?

Comment: why do you need to interact with VSC, VSC call the push command and that is it.